# Summing across columns in a block of a multi column dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-colum dataframe in pandas which looks similar to this, it is also multi index:

```
                Asset1                    Asset2                  
          private public classified private public classified
    Bank1       2      4          5       3      4          5
    Bank2       6      7          8       9     10         11
```

I want to add a column which sums over the columns for each asset. The name should be the same for both columns. I want the output to look like this:

```
                 Asset1                         Asset2                  
          private public classified total private public classified total
    Bank1       2      4       5     11     3      4          5      12
    Bank2       6      7       8     21     9     10         11      30
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach (assuming your original dataframe is `df`):

```
# sum across columns for each asset and add a new 'total' column
totals = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
totals.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col, "total") for col in totals.columns])
# concatenate and sort new columns
out = pd.concat([df, totals], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

```
           Asset1                          Asset2                     
       classified private public total classified private public total
Bank1           5       2      4    11          5       3      4    12
Bank2           8       6      7    21         11       9     10    30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    ("Asset1", "private"): [2, 6],
    ("Asset1", "public"): [4, 7],
    ("Asset1", "classified"): [5, 8],
    ("Asset2", "private"): [3, 9],
    ("Asset2", "public"): [4, 10],
    ("Asset2", "classified"): [5, 11],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["Bank1", "Bank2"])
```

Calculate the sum for each asset and add a new column named total.

```
for asset in df.columns.levels[0]:
    total_level = (asset, "total")
    df[total_level] = df[asset].sum(axis=1)
```

However, our output is like now. So we need to rearrange columns.

```
       Asset1                    Asset2                   Asset1 Asset2
      private public classified private public classified  total  total
Bank1       2      4          5       3      4          5     11     12
Bank2       6      7          8       9     10         11     21     30
```

For arranggin columns follow this algorithm and rearrange.

```
columns = []
for asset in df.columns.levels[0]:
    for column in df.columns.levels[1]:
        columns.append((asset, column))

df = df[columns]
```

Output will is like

```
          Asset1                          Asset2
      classified private public total classified private public total
Bank1          5       2      4    11          5       3      4    12
Bank2          8       6      7    21         11       9     10    30
```

So we need to reorder columns so need to use `reindex` and `pd.MultiIndex`

```
df = df.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Asset1", "Asset2"], ["private", "public", "classified", "total"]]))
```

Now final output is :

```
       Asset1                          Asset2
      private public classified total private public classified total
Bank1       2      4          5    11       3      4          5    12
Bank2       6      7          8    21       9     10         11    30
```